# How to implement an interface if a field implements that interface

Tags: java, implementation

```
public interface Function {

    double apply(double arg);

    Function derivative();

    String toString();

}

public interface Integrable extends Function {

    Function integrate();

}

public class Sum implements Function {

    private Function func1, func2;

    public Sum(Function func1, Function func2) {
        this.func1 = func1;
        this.func2 = func2;
    }

    @Override
    public double apply(double arg) {
        return func1.apply(arg) + func2.apply(arg);
    }

    @Override
    public Function derivative() {
        return new Sum(func1.derivative(), func2.derivative());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return func1.toString() + " + " + func2.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Function integrate() {
        //TODO only allow if (this instanceof Integrable)
        try {
            return new Sum(((Integrable) func1).integrate(), ((Integrable) func2).integrate());
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("could not call integrate on one of the functions of this sum, as it is not of type Integrable");
        }
    }

}
```

I'm trying to make the `Sum` class above, but it should only be of type `Integrable` if both functions are also `Integrable`. Otherwise, it should just be a `Function`.

Is there any way to do this efficiently, or is it better to make it `Integrable` by default and check the 2 fields in `integrate()`?

Comment: Recommendations for a better title are welcome

Comment: I'd recommend that you learn the Java 8 lambda API.  You can do these things without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: java doesn't support explicit interface implementation like c#... too bad.. you could use it here.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that that the parameter of `Sum` must take an `Integrable` in that case.

You can create two classes - `Sum` and `IntegrableSum` (uhh.. need a better name)

```
class Sum implements Function {
    public Sum(Function func1, Function func2) {
       ....
    }
}

class IntegrableSum implements Integrable {
    public IntegrableSum(Integrable integrable1, Integrable integrable2) {
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Too bad I can't do this using the same class name. This way, it would be better for me to just check integrability in `integrate()`

Comment: You can check that. But what can you do if the underlying functions are not `Integrable`? Throw an exception? In that case, the Javadoc of `Integrable` has to specify this which is not great. The problem here is that you cannot dynamically add methods to a class (or change the type of a class dynamically)

Comment: The complete mathematics program is an exercise for my study, so I don't need to, as the code will never be used after. Since I'm learning the language, I wanted to know if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you create adapter classes that implement the `Integrable` interface, provide default implementations to the respective abstract methods of your choice. But I don't think you can create a class in Java based on conditions as classes created in Java is direct, I mean you should know what your class is all about before creation.

Comment: Unfortunately, my scope doesn't allow that. The classes have to accept any function, not just integrables.

Comment: Then make it a Function, since Integrable is a Function. The unfortunate thing here is, if the two fields are Integrable, you cannot change the superclass Function anymore but then, it doesn't matter, but if it's not, better, because Integrable is a Function.